# How do i enable users to style their input in a text field?

Tags: html, css, web

I am working on a site that has a feature where users have to input text which can be read later by all users on the site. I want the users to be able to style their input for example make a few lines bold or italic, a good example is the comment box on this site. I also need advice on how to save this text with the styling in a mysql database. Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this site uses http://commonmark.org/ which is a fork of Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use HTML editor like [this](http://nicedit.com/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use any WYSIWYG editor (eg. http://ckeditor.com/) and save data in database as HTML that editor generates.

Answer (score 1):

you can add your styles directly to db without doing extra things. But be carefull about `' "` characters while writing to db.